# Can't upload to google docs from php 400 error!

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

Hi guys I'm trying to upload to google docs on a google apps account using the following code - I'm using zend framework:

```
function getGoogleClient($s = '')
{
  $service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; 

  $user = 'aaaaa';
  $pass = 'aaaaa';

  $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);

  return $httpClient;
}

function uploadDocument($docs, $html, $originalFileName, $temporaryFileLocation) {
    $fileToUpload = $originalFileName;
    if ($temporaryFileLocation) {
        $fileToUpload = $temporaryFileLocation;
    }

    $newDocumentEntry = $docs->uploadFile($fileToUpload, $originalFileName, null, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);

}



$client = getGoogleClient();
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
$ls = uploadDocument($docs, true, $file->filename, $file->tmp_name);
```

BUt I keep getting this error - whats wrong here :(

```
Expected response code 200, got 400 Inconsistent repeating query parameter
```

Comment: this code is working for me (calling `uploadDocument()` with `$file->tmp_name` being `null`). are your credentials correct? can you upload docs via webinterface? what kind of file are you trying to upload? is another program accessing the document (try closing word or excel or openoffice)?

Comment: null? I'm passing to it file->tmp_name refers to the temporary location of a uploaded file as in $_FILES[tmp_name]

Comment: `null` for debugging if your code works for uploading a local file to google docs - with your code in a php script, without webserver (`$_FILES[tmp_name]`). which it does. so your problem is somewhere else. either in the things i mentioned above, or in your tmp file handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "bug" in Zend_Gdata_Docs with the mimetype.
If you are using a temporary file and the filename as the title it will not auto-magically pull the mimetype for you. It tries to pull the mimetype based on the fileLocation extension which does not exist on a temporary file.

I made a class that works for me, rather than updating the Zend class.
It is called [ConvertDoc](http://blog.artistandesigns.com/2011/02/zendgdata-lacks-document-download.html) because I wanted to be able to [upload a spreadsheet and download as csv.](http://blog.artistandesigns.com/2011/02/zendgdata-lacks-document-download.html)

What you really need is this...

```
    // get mimetype from original file name
    $filenameParts = explode('.', $originalFileName);
    $fileExtension = end($filenameParts);
    $mimeType = Zend_Gdata_Docs::lookupMimeType($fileExtension);
```

And pass the $mimetype instead of null.